# C Programming: Redefine a macro defined in the shared library(.so)

Tags: c

I want to override the macro defined in the shared library.

For example:

libxyz.so (a shared library) has

```
#define ADDRESS 0

int some_func()
{
   ...
   func_use_addr(ADDRESS);
}
```

Now I write a code where the ADDRESS that I want "some_func()" to use is (say) 0xabc36000.

Can I redefine the ADDRESS macro in my.c file so that it'll be used as the 0xabc36000 and not 0 in the `some_func()`?

I understand that macros are replaced during pre-processing stage, and linking with shared library happens later. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with out modifying the shared library code.

Comment: You answer your own question in the last paragraph. Just to restate it clearly: No, this is not possible.

Comment: A shared library don't have preprocessor symbols (only source code have them). So you could recompile your shared library from source code

Comment: You will have to override the whole function `some_func()` containing a call to `func_use_addr()` with the new address as parameter.

Comment: There are *no* macros in the library as it is already compiled. So there is nothing to redefine.

Comment: Recompile the lib with the right macro or if you'll want to do dynamic interposition after the recompilation, replace the macro with a global with default visibility (`__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))` if you're compiling with `-fvisibility=hidden`). There's no way to override intermediate values in finished shared libraries.

Comment: Well, you could try and alter the value in the binary if it hasn't been optimized out, but that's the last resort really.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can redefine a macro.

```
#ifdef ADDRESS
#undef ADDRESS
#endif

#define ADDRESS 0xabc36000
```

Comment: ... but no, it won't do anything to a shared object that has already been preprocessed, compiled and linked.